# Run barebone arduino on 3Volts battery

Tags: arduino, avr

i have finished building my barebone arduino..i want to run the barebone chip with 3V battery i.e double AA 1.5 x 2= 3V..the reason i am persisting using 3V Vcc is because in our project we need to fit in the battery in a given battery slot which is very small..A 9V battery is able to fit in it..currently we are using a 9V battery but the LM7805 regulator is consuming a lot of current..which wont be efficient in future..when we want save battery power and what not..we wont be able to fit in 3X 1.5V i.e 4.5V.

anyways my question is would i able to use 3V directly on my barebone..I will replace my 16Mhz crystal clock with a 8MHz one..because 3V wont work with 16mhz..but how will i source the voltage..some assistance would be really helpful...thanks a lot...

Comment: Just connect it directly and add a small electrolytic or big ceramic capacitor, 10uF should be enough. Most ATMegas can work down to 1.8V, so ensure that the oscillator can work at 1.8V too.

Comment: directly as in so just connect the the Vcc wire of battery straight into 3.3Volts pin whatever that would be on the atmega barebone ..and Gnd to Gnd pin..would that be it??

Comment: i just saw the arduino with atmega 328p schematic pin diagram...it just mentions Vcc.so that is just 5V so basically connect a capacitor of 10uF in series with the battery and gnd.

Comment: Positive battery terminal goes to VDD(=VCC), negative terminal to VSS(=GND). Capacitor goes between the two.

Comment: ok thanks buddy..but there is more to this issue.whenever we right something HIGH it means 5V and LOW means GND..i read somewhere vaguely that if we use 3V or lower voltage source..we need to change AREF voltage to 3 rather then 5V otherwise i/o pins wont work..something along those lines..any idea about that??

Comment: no @riju when you write a pin "HIGH" it just sources voltage and current from the VCC rail. If VCC is 3V, that is what the HIGH output will be. AREF has nothing to do with it. AREF is used for internally routing the analog ADC peripheral's reference voltage allowing you to compare certain custom input voltages giving you the full range of 1042 (10bit resolution). For example you could put a 1.24V high accuracy VREF chip onto AREF and then measure something between 0-1.24V with 1024 points, rather than 5V/1024 giving only 0-254 points. You would quadrupal your accuracy by doing so.

Comment: ahhh i get it now..so i guess this would be suffice...for now..thanks a lot guys..really appreciate your help..hopefully will revert back to guys for power saving modes..since iam using wireless RF module 433MHz..interfaced with my barebone..so lot of power saving would be required..mostly the software part now.....anyways thanks once again..

Comment: @riju see my answer below, if it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can connect the 3V worth of AA batteries directly to VCC of the ATMEGA, and either use an external 8MHz oscillator (crystal or ceramic, either one works) or you can even use the internal RC osscillator with a CLKDIV2 to make your clock speed 4MHz which will work all the way down to 1.8V volts. You can also use CLKDIV settings on the external oscillators if you wanted. These options are all in the "Fuse" settings which when working with AVRs you must become familiar with. There are multiple tutorials on how to set and read fuses online, so you should be okay with some time spent researching.

This is the chart from the ATMEGA328P datasheet (page 316) showing the VCC voltage versus acceptable frequency of guaranteed operation.

[image: Clock frequency vs VCC voltage from page 316]

You can hook up the batteries to VCC pins of the microcontroller directly with just a power decoupling capacitor to help during digital "on/off" cycles and other forms of power spikes. Here is an example of how I do it. In your case the power net label "VCC" is literally the battery +pos terminals, and the "GND" net label is your battery -neg terminal.

[image: Example of connecting stuff to power ATMEGA328P]

good luck!

Comment: ok will surely have a look on fuse settings for the future..this schematic diagram is actually really helpful..so basically i have to remake the chip..this time getting rid of LM7805 altogether..one headache gone...in my schematic diagram only one pin 7 is Vcc and pin 20 is AVcc(Vcc)..so i short that..then i short the GND pins 8 and 22..then i connect a 10uF capacitor in series with the Vcc and Gnd...is that it?? is 0.1uF really required???

Comment: "is 0.1uF really required???" - Yes, as close to the chip as possible, see the datasheets. - Remember that the battery voltage may drop over time, so try to make sure the controller can run @ 2.7V or 2.5V too (maybe even lower), for good run time on batteries. - Later, you may want to also have a look at the AVR's "System Clock Prescaler" (CLKPR), if you want to scale the system's frequency at runtime for efficiency.

Comment: @HannoBinder Alkaline batteries can be successfully discharged below 1V, see [discharge curve](http://madscientisthut.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2011/01/AA-100mA.png)

Comment: That's right. Yet, the µC will probably not run at 12Mhz on 2.5V, while it does on 3V. On 2V only about 5Mhz will be safe. So don't go to the limit for 3V when using batteries.

Comment: Riju if you have the DIP package version, check the datasheet and schematics for the correct pins for VCC and AVCC and all the GND pins. 

@HannoBinder yeah so Riji will be going to at least 8MHz, but I think 4MHz is probably good enough for whatever he/she is doing, except for perhaps high baud-rate serial comms.

Comment: @KyranF this is the picture i was talking about while checking the pin configuration..do keep in mind that i will be burning the code on the actual arduino uno..before using it on the barebone arduino..just for the info i also have an RF trasmitter interfaced with the barebone..and later on in my project i want the RF transmitter to wake up once every 4 hours.. check whatever it needs to check and transmit data and go back to sleep.. and repeat that every 4 hours..

Comment: sorry and here is the link...http://computerpr0n.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/Atmega168PinMap2.png

Comment: @riju Yes, that looks okay then. 

can you please double check that the RF transmitter device can operate correctly on 2.5-3V, and also that it's logic level output is within range for the ATMEGA to detect logic high/low? Do you know what I mean by this?

Comment: @kyranF yes it is within voltage range..iam sorry i didnt get the latter part..currently iam using Rf module with the barebone chip i have made with using 9V battery...and it working fine..can you kindly explain me the latter part thanks..

Comment: @riju you are using a voltage regulator right now, to get 5V out of the 9V battery for the Arduino and the RF module? Well when you start using 3V, do you know if the RF module will still work? Are you able to find a datasheet or schematic for it?

Comment: well it says that voltage operting range is from 3V- 12V..ahhh  i see what you mean..if voltage drops below 3V it would stop transmitting...the smd versions of it have lesser operating voltage..any other suggestions??

Comment: if you can find an RF module that works for your purposes down to 2.4-2.5V you will be okay. The next possible thing is a low power voltage doubler "charge pump" (or other forms of DC-DC boost converters) you can get very cheap and simple ones for low currents like 50mA etc. This will give it more like 5V to operate on

Comment: i have ordered nRF24L01 transcievers..it mentions in some website that operating voltage is 1.8V onwards..so it is on its way...one new thing i want to ask is that iam planning to use atmega 328P SMD version. Does anyone know how to burn i.e bootload it..thanks

Comment: @riju yes you need to access the SPI bus pins (MISO, MOSI, SCLK) as well as RESET (with pull up 10k ohm resistor) and VCC and GND (6 pins in total!) And use either a proper AVR ISP MkII or a cheaper programmer such as the USB ASP. I have a USB ASP, i bought mine from ebay for a few dollars. Make sure your USBASP is set to 3.3V target because it can actually power the target for you. You can burn the arduino bootloader using the arduino IDE. After that you need to use TX/RX to do the normal arduino programming. You may need a serial->USB converter like an FTDI chip.